# Meaning of "ja doch eher" in context

Tags: adverb

I came across this [graffiti](http://www.kraftfuttermischwerk.de/blogg/nazis-find-ich-personlich-ja-doch-eher-uncool/) which says:

> "Nazis find ich persönlich ja doch eher uncool"

The way I would translate this in English would be:

> Personally I *still* think Nazis are uncool.

Is this correct and are there any nuances in this sentence by using "ja doch eher" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of these words adds a little to the whole sentence:

- *find* is colloquial, especially when combined as *find ich*, which is often pronounced as *findich*
- *persönlich* just emphasizes the non-objective nature
- *ja* typically means *as I (and maybe you) already knew before*; in many other cases it weakens the argument
- *doch* makes the sentence sound unsure, as in *na gut, ich komme doch mit, du hast mich überredet*
- *eher* makes the argument even weaker, it's approximately at 60%, so very close to the middle
- *doch eher* is very close to *I'm totally unsure, but I tend to this direction*
- *uncool* is a lot weaker than *doof*, *schlecht*, which nicely matches the *ja doch eher*

Altogether, the sentence sounds like not a big thing, personal opinion, unsure. Until you get the irony.

A simple *still* doesn't provide all this heavy bag of connotation, so you need some more words.

Comment: Maybe like this? "Personally I still think Nazis are, um, y'know, uncool."

Comment: Ich finde, das *doch* wirkt bekräftigend. *Eher uncool* drückt einen gewissen Zweifel aus - das *doch* bekräftigt aber, dass eine Entscheidung gefallen ist.

Comment: Das _doch_ könnte auch auf eine neue Erkenntnis hindeuten. Wie bekräftigend auch immer es sein mag, es rennt voll in die von _eher_ aufgestellte Mauer und wird von dieser abgebremst.

Comment: Was wollte, mit anderen Worten, dieser Satz vermitteln ?

Comment: Die Kernaussage ist: _Nazis sind doof._ Die ganzen abschwächenden Formen könnten bedeuten: 1. Aber ich traue mich nicht, das so direkt zu sagen. 2. Aber ich will nicht plump erscheinen. 3. Ich kann meine Meinung differenziert ausdrücken (also keine Schwarz-Weiß-Meinung). 4. (Es gibt bestimmt noch mehr …)

Answer (score -2):

In your example "ja doch eher" is a stylistic device. It is irony and in this case you make fun of people who like Nazis. It is hard to translate a stylistic device and you would most likely change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I see, it is so unsure that it is basically an endorsement

Comment: If it is hard to translate, you could try to explain it instead.